# Looking to search and cut multiple strings from file programatically

Tags: bash, ping, trace

I am using bash just trying to write a simple script to pull a traceroute result and then pull the IP address from this result, and then run a continuous ping to each of the hops to return a result. I am looking for the simplest way to scour my traceroute results, and add the IP addresses to variables. My thought is to just use the "(" to start the search... pull all the data after this... stop at the ")"... and then add it to the variable... and then loop until the count of the initial "(" is done. Any suggestions on how I might do this? I have done a little research on the csplit, find, and cut command, but have been unable to come up with anything that would meet my needs. Any help ou can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the traceroute output you're trying to parse and an example of what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

This may get you started:

```
traceroute somehost.example.com | sed 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/'
```